# How to stop parallel from reporting "No more processes" with "-X" option?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Working off this example: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Speeding-up-fast-jobs

When I run:

```
seq -w 0 9999 | parallel touch pict{}.jpg
seq -w 0 9999 | parallel -X touch pict{}.jpg
```

Success! However, add another 9 and BOOM:

`$ seq -w 0 99999 | parallel --eta  -X touch pict{}.jpg
parallel: Warning: No more processes: Decreasing number of running jobs to 3. Raising ulimit -u or /etc/security/limits.conf may help.
Computers / CPU cores / Max jobs to run
1:local / 4 / 3
parallel: Warning: No more processes: Decreasing number of running jobs to 2. Raising ulimit -u or /etc/security/limits.conf may help.
parallel: Warning: No more processes: Decreasing number of running jobs to 1. Raising ulimit -u or /etc/security/limits.conf may help.
parallel: Error: No more processes: cannot run a single job. Something is wrong.`

I would expect `parallel -X` to run no more jobs than I have cpu cores, and to cram as many parameters onto each job as the max command line length permits. How am I running out of processes?

My environment:

- OSX Yosemite
- `ulimit -u` == 709
- GNU parallel 20141122
- GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is 100% correct. What you are seeing is clearly a bug - probably due to GNU Parallel not being well tested on OSX. Please follow http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS and file a bug report.